managing reqIds to start and stop streaming
The following code is supposed to start and stop options streaming data, but no matter what I do I get AttributeError: 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'reqId', or No reqId found for contract or such. Can anyone help me get a handle on reqId?
'''
from ib_insync import IB, Option
active_tickers = {}

def start_streaming_option(ib, option):
    """Starts market data streaming for a given option and prints ask price."""
    ib.qualifyContracts(option)
    ticker = ib.reqMktData(option)
    ticker.updateEvent += lambda t: print(f"{ticker.contract.symbol} {ticker.contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth} {ticker.contract.strike} {ticker.contract.right}: Ask {t.ask}")
    # Store the ticker using the contract's conId as the key
    active_tickers[ticker.contract.conId] = ticker
    print(f"Streaming started with reqId {ticker.reqId} for contract {ticker.contract.conId}")
    return ticker

def stop_streaming_option(ib, option):
    """Stops market data streaming for a given option."""
    if option.conId in active_tickers:
        ticker = active_tickers[option.conId]
        ib.cancelMktData(ticker)
        del active_tickers[option.conId]
        print(f"Streaming stopped for contract {option.conId}")
    else:
        print("Ticker not found for cancellation. Check if it's the right contract.")

def main():
    ib = IB()
    ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=1)

    # Define two options to stream
    option1 = Option('SPY', '20240426', 504, 'C', 'CBOE')
    option2 = Option('SPY', '20240426', 505, 'P', 'CBOE')

    # Start streaming the first option
    print("Starting to stream option1...")
    ticker1 = start_streaming_option(ib, option1)
    
    # Wait for keyboard input to switch options
    input("Press Enter to switch to the second option...")

    # Switch to the second option
    print("Switching to option2...")
    stop_streaming_option(ib, option1)
    ticker2 = start_streaming_option(ib, option2)

    # Wait for another input to stop streaming
    input("Press Enter to stop streaming and exit...")
    stop_streaming_option(ib, option2)

    # Disconnect the session
    ib.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

'''
